# undefined for useContext in reactjs multilevel components

Tags: reactjs, undefined, use-context

in my src, I have State.js for create-context as follow
State.js
I**'m using react js current version and using public and private route**

```
    import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react"
    let AppsContext = createContext({});
    const initialState = {
    appName : "Arrman",
    user : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arrman-as-user")),
    }
    let reducer = ( state, action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case "setAppName" : {
            return {...state, appName : action.payload.appName }
        }
        case "loadUser" : {
            const user = action.payload;
            localStorage.setItem("whatapp-clone-user",JSON.stringify(user));
            return {...state, user: user }
        }
        default:
            break;
       }
     }
     function AppsContextProvider(props) {
     const appState = {
        ...initialState
     }
     let [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, appState);
     let value = {state, dispatch};
     return <AppsContext.Provider value={ value }>{props.children}</AppsContext.Provider>
     }
     export { AppsContext, AppsContextProvider}
```

---

// in my App.js I am creating component so I can use theme as per authentication

```
    import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { AppsContext } from './AppState';
    import CreateRoutes from './routes/createRoutes';
    const App = () => {
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(AppsContext);
    console.log(state)
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <CreateRoutes></CreateRoutes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    );
    }
    export default App;
```

---

// in my CreateRouters.js

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute';
    import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
    const CreateRoutes = () => {
    return (
    <>
      <PrivateRoute></PrivateRoute>
      <PublicRoute></PublicRoute>
    </>  
    )
    }
    export default CreateRoutes;
```

---

Comment: 1. Was there an error message. Maybe posting the error message below your code would be more helpful. 2. Can you add more description to each of your code files? I could be wrong but it seems to me you cannot use useContext as a React hook. Theme providers, like any other React providers, should be wrapping around your ```App``` class because it works in a global context. Maybe you should try something like this is index.js: ```<AppContextProvider><App /></AppContextProvider>```. Don't forget to import the definition of AppContextProvider to index.js.

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't define a theme provider class with in-line HTML code inside a state/reducer file because reducers are very different than any other components in a react-redux model (and reducers are highly reusable), unless there's a good reason for this design.